# How to create a logo for mvnrepository artifact

Tags: java, maven, repository

There are a logo on artifcats in [mvnrepository](http://mvnrepository.com/). Can't find the way to do that. 
Example: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.nifi/nifi-api

This is my artifact and the icon is {h}: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ru.sadv1r.vk/vk-parser

How to change it?