# Add icon to mvnrepository website?

Tags: maven

A lot of dependencies on the `MvnRepository` website https://mvnrepository.com/ display an icon (thumbnail). How can one integrate an icon? And what should the measurements be in pixel?

I host my library on `MvnCentral` and have not found any option to do that. `MvnCentral` doesn't even displan an icon.

How can one add the logo on the github repository in order that mvncentral retrieves it? Apparently one does not have to extend the pom.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40197177/how-to-create-a-logo-for-mvnrepository-artifact) question says that it is possible, but not precisely how. Does anybody have a reference?

Furthermore does anyone have an example of a logo specified within a pom.xml?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a logo for mvnrepository artifact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40197177/how-to-create-a-logo-for-mvnrepository-artifact)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Icons and tags on mvnrepository.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30661826/icons-and-tags-on-mvnrepository-com).